# stable diffusion with controlnet, api

Tags: stable-diffusion

I use stable diffusion and controlnet and a model (control_sd15_scribble [fef5e48e]) to generate images. The image that is generated I nice and almost the same as the image that is uploaded. But I want to make a website and use the web api and I try to get the same result like the image that you see.

[image]

I try to get the same result in postman, but I cant. This is my post request and the json is the body request:

```
http://localhost:7860/sdapi/v1/img2img
{  
"prompt": "RAW photo, kitchen, 8k uhd, dslr, soft lighting, high quality",
"negative_prompt": "semi-realistic, cgi, sketch, cartoon, drawing, anime:1.4), text, 
close up, cropped, out of frame, worst quality, low quality, jpeg artifacts, ugly",
"steps": 20,
"init_images": ["here the image ..."],
"sampler_name": "Euler",
"alwayson_scripts": {
"controlnet": {
  "args": [{
      "module": "none",
      "model": "control_sd15_scribble [fef5e48e]"
    }]
   }
  }
 }
```